# Visual Studio 2022 open in new tab on ctrl + click

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In visual studio 2022, when I ctr + click a method, I want to jump to the definition in new tab even if the definition is in the same file.

I can't track where I left currently since I enter several different methods while I read the code.

Comment: You can also jump back (and forward) to previous location using back and forward mouse buttons.

Comment: you are right but when i enter more than 3 methods in the same file and analyse several lines i need to hit back more than 10, again i loose track of where i left

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet possible. An extension plug-in (if it exists or one developed by you) might do the job. For now, the only thing that might help you out is using **Bookmarks**. Indeed, "travelling" back using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> might be daunting, but it's the only way possible (which is why I recommend **Bookmarks** combined with navigation).

TLDR: Not yet possible. Maybe make an extension *OR* the closest you can get is if you use Bookmarks alongside navigation.